# Firebase Admin SDK, FCM Cloud Messaging

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using Firebase Admin SDK for cloud messaging and I have used GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, on Firebase I have added Android app, should I download Sdk file for that app and how can I test my notifications? Where should I get FCM token for test?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using cloud shell to deploy the application? Here is a useful document by google on how o get the `FCM token` and how to setup the SDK [1]

[1] https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message#retrieve-the-current-registration-token